# TTStyledTextLabel's url's font

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, three20

Hey guys, in the TTStyledTextLabel, the url's font is a bit bigger(from what i noticed) and is blue-ish.
I am just wondering how to change the url's font to a smaller size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the sample in StyledTextTestController from the TTCatalog. You need to override the TTDefaultStyleSheet with your own style and add the span class to the url as shown in the example.

Comment: How did you get this working? Putting the span tag around the links doesn't seem to change their font. Adding the class to the links themselves changes the font but then the links can no longer be tapped!